# Making mod-12 counter using ic7492

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, counter

There is this exercise in my book said to make a mod 6, mod 4, mod 3, mod 12 counter using 7492. I can do mod 6, 4, and 3 but there is a problem when doing mod 12.
The circuit counts to 5 then skip to 8, how can I fix this problem?

[image: the circuit I used]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the datasheet of the 7492 we can easily confirm that the mod12 counter has 12 different states but the codes do not match a binary counter.

[image]